# Tcpdump is not capturing traffic in whole network

Tags: tcpdump

Isn't this command is supposed to capture whole network traffic

```
**tcpdump -i any net "192.168.1.0/24 "**
```

nothing is being shown on terminal.

Comment: `tcpdump` can only show you traffic that's actually handled by your NIC, so without a more advanced configuration there's no way for it to show you. Maybe a better question would be "how can i monitor all traffic on my network using tcpdump"

Comment: In other words: on a modern switched network by default the switches take care that rather than all network packets, only the network packets for actually destined for your system (and broadcast traffic) will be transmitted to the port(s) your system is connected to.

Comment: And because of the filter ARP requests which are broadcast but not IP packets, won't be seen. Try again without filter (or say, filtering the port 22 if remote access is through ssh: `not port 22`), chances are you'll see at least ARP about your system twice a minute if it's actually using the network, and possibly more unrelated to your system.

Comment: `tcpdump -i any`
But this would only capture all network interfaces. If you need to capture a whole network you might need a special port on a switch with port mirror